# Right-align text with another text viz on an image, in responsive layout

Tags: css, image, responsive-design

I have a page that has an `image` which contains text in it. There is a text outside of the image that needs to be right-aligned with the text within the image. I've tried handling this with percentages which worked for some sizes, but not for all.

Trying to figure out if there is an easy way to do this that works for all and for responsive layout too.

Example:

[image: Example Image]

Comment: Please attach your code

Comment: It can be done but the details will depend in part on your image and the HTML around it.  Post your code!

Comment: How's this for you? https://jsfiddle.net/n451c4ym/2/ the "bottom" css property would need to be adjusted - but with that setup the right hand side of the text remains inline with the fixed text on the image...

Comment: Try using `vw` on positioning. eg.: `right: 2vw;`

Comment: Is the image's size depends on the width of the window?

Comment: Thanks @lukeTwomey that is exactly what I needed. If you want to post that as the solution I can mark that as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How's this for you? https://jsfiddle.net/n451c4ym/2/ the "bottom" css property would need to be adjusted - but with that setup the right hand side of the text remains inline with the fixed text on the image...

Basically you give the parent a position of relative:

```
.imageContainer{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

and make the text a child of that container (along with the image). Then by making your html text width 100%, it should scale at the same proportions as the image (and in turn the fixed image text):

```
.imageContainer img{
    width: 100%;
}


.text{
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50%;
    padding-right: 7vw;
    right: 0;
    text-align: right;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I needed.